# Owin Selfhost Webapi - How to set MaxReceivedMessageSize to allow large files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

Prior to the Owin version of the self host webapi it was possible to define the MaxRecievedMessageSize like this to allow for larger files transfer:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483648;
```

Is that possible with the Owin Selfhost approach?

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own OWIN middleware for that. Kiran Challa wrote an example that suits your needs at the asp.net forums, http://forums.asp.net/post/5622974.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Im trying to do the opposite: Increase the default message size to enable sending larger files. But maybe that is already allowed with Owin Selfhost?